# Command Prompt Changing Colors after Compile

Tags: windows, cmd, compiler-errors

Whenever I run a compiler on a bash cmd and I get an error, the command prompt changes back to 'default' like colors. It stays like this till I change it manually again.

I have tried changing "right click->properties->color" and "right click->defaults->color" and I have went where the cmd is in the file system and change the color through properties. Same problem occurs.

I am very unsure where else I could change the color to fix this problem.

System = Razerblade Steath 2017

OS = Updated Windows 10

Compilers Using = g++ and gcc (same problem on both)

Picture of how and when it occurs. The code I am running is just one line in the main function purposely giving an error.
[image: Picture of how and when it occurs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`-fno-diagnostics-color`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html) on your command line to disable this.  gcc tries to determine if your window supports color and it will use it to try to make the error messages easier to read.  Apparently, it's not restoring the original colors correctly.

Windows command prompts stopped supporting [color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) long ago, but that feature has recently be re-enabled in one of the Windows 10 releases.

Comment: I'm sorry windows command prompt (cmd.exe)  has always supported colour using the `color` command or the API `SetConsoleTextAttribute`. You are referring to ANSI terminal codes. And it seems stupid to bring them back. In DOS it wasn't enabled by default.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the ANSI terminal control codes, but I felt that detail would be more distracting than useful, which is why I buried it in the "color" link in my answer.